# Регулярное выражение на номер телефона

Tags: php

На сайте есть регулярка на ввод номера телефона

```
echo'                       <div class="profile__input-row">
                            <input class="profile__input" type="text" id="User_PhoneNum" name="tel" value="'.$row_inf['t_numb'].'"/ required pattern=^\+?[\s\-\(\)0-9]{7,19}$ title="Enter the phone in the format +x(xxx)xx-xx-xx" >';
```

Но все равно можно вводить абсолютно любые цифры, в чем проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что наличие атрибута 'pattern' у input'а не запрещает ввод других символов, не подходящих под этот паттерн. Он срабатывает после нажатия кнопки типа Submit формы и в этом случае запускается проверка введенного значения на соответствие шаблону. [Подробнее](http://htmlbook.ru/html/input/pattern).

Если соответствия нет, то форма не отправится дальше. Кроме того, при потере фокуса с элемента ввода и нажатии обычных кнопок (type="button") валидация так же не сработает.

```
<form action="?" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="phone" required="required" pattern="^\+?[\s\-\(\)0-9]{7,19}$"><br />
    <input type="button" name="simple_button" value="Don't work"><br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Work">
</form>
```

Если вы хотите динамически проверять вводимые символы, то необходимо использовать JavaScript на странице. Можно воспользоваться одной из готовых библиотек по заданию масок, [например](https://css-tricks.com/input-masking/).

Answer (score 0):

Рискну предположить что проблема в том, что строку регулярного выражения следует взять в кавычки так как это атрибут html.

Comment: В Chrome 60+ версии сработает из без кавычек. Попробуйте:
<input type="text" name="phone" required="required" pattern=^\+?[\s\-\(\)0-9]{7,19}$ />